# How to find the bytes per second

Tags: php, audio, duration, unpack

I want to find how many bytes per second are used in a mp3 file in order to be able to find the duration of the audio file.
Im using the script below and it shows me some strange values. Im not really familiar with all this audio file things and i would appreciate some help.

```
function getDuration($file) {
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    $size_in_bytes = filesize($file);
    fseek($fp, 20);
    $rawheader = fread($fp, 16);
    $header = unpack('vtype/vchannels/Vsamplerate/Vbytespersec/valignment/vbits', $rawheader);
    print_r($header);
    $sec = ceil($size_in_bytes/$header['bytespersec']);
    return $sec;
}
```

The output on print_r is

```
Array ( [type] => 25936 [channels] => 27489 [samplerate] => 1970037078 [bytespersec] => 2110652517 [alignment] => 0 [bits] => 21072 )
```

So this **bytespersec** rate (2 110 652 517) is confusing me.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/36871/linux-command-line-utility-to-determine-mp3-bitrate

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the ffmpeg extension for php?

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php